# Strange missing required key in RSpec controller test for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Testing an Rails Controller (for an API) in RSpec for a nested resource (orders has_many order_actions):

```
it "returns status OK" do
  order_action = create(:order_action)
  order_action.update_attribute(:order_id, @order.id)
  put :update, {:id => order_action.id, :order_id => @order.id, :order_action => valid_attributes}.merge(valid_session)
  expect(response.code).to eql("200")
end
```

(`valid_attributes` is just `build(:order_action).attributes`. `valid_session` is `{:user_email => @user.email, :user_token => @user.authentication_token, :format => 'json'}`.)

I get an annoying error `missing required keys: [:order_id]`. Annoying because it is, as you can see, explicitly defined above. Twice. Here's the error text:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/order_actions", :format=>nil, :id=>#<OrderAction id: 19, order_id: 3, created_at: "2015-03-13 15:52:13", updated_at: "2015-03-13 15:52:13">, :order_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:order_id]
```

And the relevant failed test report

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/order_actions_controller_spec.rb:151 # Api::V1::OrderActionsController PUT #update with valid params returns status OK
```

Notice two errors: `:order_id` and `:format` are `nil`.

Now, things get even weirder if you run the exact same test alone:

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/order_actions_controller_spec.rb:151
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/controllers/order_actions_controller_spec.rb"=>[151]}}
.

Finished in 0.16575 seconds (files took 3.62 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

The test passes! I'm losing my mind. Help?

---

**Additional Info**

`@order` and `@user` creation at the top of the `order_actions_controller_spec.rb`:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = create(:user)
  @order = create(:order)
end
```

Order and User factories:

```
a_user = User.new({:email => "#{SecureRandom.hex(3)}@rakuten.com", :password => "!abc123%@#", :password_confirmation =>  "!abc123%@#"})

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do
    user a_user
    class_code "MyText"
    class_name "MyString"
    complete false
  end
end
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "#{SecureRandom.hex(3)}@email.com"
    password "!abc123%@#"
    password_confirmation { "!abc123%@#" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `@order` defined?

Comment: @BroiSatse in before(:each) block

Comment: I meant if you could show this part of the code. Error is raise because `order_id` is nil and it is required to build the correct path to update action.

Comment: @BroiSatse FYI I posted the additional code

Comment: last question, what is in `valid session`?

Comment: @BroiSatse No problem:  `{:user_email => @user.email, :user_token => @user.authentication_token, :format => 'json'}`